# eliminar registros de una tabla desde un enlace con php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, crud

Tengo una tabla que me lista los registros de mi Base de Datos. Al lado de cada registro, aparece un botón para actualizar y otro para eliminar:

```
    <table border="1">
  <tr>
<td>ID de Empleado</td>
<td>Nombre</td>
<td>Apellidos</td>
<td>Email</td>
<td>Coste por Hora</td>
<td>Departamento</td>
<td>Foto</td>
<td colspan="2">Opciones</td>
  </tr>
@foreach ($empleado as $emp)
<tr>
  <td>{{$emp->idEmpleado}}</td>
  <td>{{$emp->nombre}}</td>
  <td>{{$emp->apellidos}}</td>
  <td>{{$emp->email}}</td>
  <td>{{$emp->costeHora}}</td>
  <td>{{$emp->departamento}}</td>
  <td>{{$emp->foto}}</td>
  <td><a href="{{route('empleadoVista.edit', $emp->id)}}">Editar</a></td>
  <td><a href="">Eliminar</a></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

La función de Editar funciona perfectamente. Lo que necesito saber es como eliminar un registro haciendo click directamente en el enlace y que me retorne de nuevo a la misma lista de registros. No quiero pasar por ninguna otra vista.

Sé que el envío se realiza mediante el método delete() que luego será recogido en mi controlador. Este es mi controlador:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
  $empleado=Empleado::findOrFail($id);

  $empleado->delete();

  return redirect("empleadoVista/listarTodos");
}
```

Y en la ruta tengo un método que se supone que asigna las rutas a los métodos por defecto del CRUD:

```
Route::resource('empleadoVista', 'EmpleadoControlador');
```

Comment: Y no puedes retornar simplemente la vista en la que ya estas? O quieres configurarlo por AJAX?

Comment: Sí @FranciscoGarrido. Quiero retornar a la vista en la que estoy pero habiendo eliminado el registro. Nada de AJAX de momento ;)

Answer (score 1):

El metodo resource te crea un CRUD para que pueda ser consumido posteriormente, pero estoy no te funcionara con enlaces normales.

Para ello crea la siguiente ruta:

```
Route::get('delete/{id}', 'EmpleadoControlador@destroy')->name('empleado.delete');
```

Y creamos el enlace de eliminar en tu tabla:

```
  <td><a href="{{route('empleado.delete', $emp->id)}}">Eliminar</a></td>
```

El metodo del controlador ya lo tienes bien definido. Aunque nunca esta de más tener alguna comprobación.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
  $empleado=Empleado::findOrFail($id);

  if ($empleado->delete()) {
      return redirect("empleadoVista/listarTodos");
  }

  return 'Algo ha salido mal';
}
```

Comment: Había un error en la línea Route::get('delete/{id}', 'delete@EmpleadoControlador')->name('empleado.delete'); Lo correcto sería: Route::get('delete/{id}', 'EmpleadoControlador@destroy')->name('empleado.delete'); Lo he cambiado y funciona correctamente. Aunque aún me surge una duda... ¿Esta forma de hacerlo es correcta? Pues estoy viendo que al meter la misma url a mano, puedo borrar registros a mi antojo, por lo que no parece seguro...

Comment: Lo suyo seria que como mínimo, metieses un middleware para asegurarse de que quien lo hace es un usuario con privilegios. Tambien seria utilizar AJAX, y el metodo delete, para que no sea tan sencillo como entrar a una URL. Pero vamos, con un middleware deberia valer. `Route::middleware('auth')->get('delete/{id}', 'EmpleadoControlador@delete')->name('empleado.delete');`. Esto hara que solo usuarios registrados puedan borrar.

Comment: El middleware me da error:
InvalidArgumentException
Route [login] not defined.
Imagino que es porque aún no tengo sistema de login... no?

Comment: Efectivamente, el middleware puede ser de cualquier tipo e incluso configurar tu uno para que tenga que pasar condiciones especificas.

Comment: Lo haré más adelante porque se trata de un proyecto serio. MUCHÍSIMAS GRACIAS @FranciscoGarrido !!!